# Help making a remix

Tags: chord-progressions, melody, daw

Recently I have been trying to make a remix for the song Revolution by Diplo.  I have the acapella for it but every time that I try to make a melody for the song it just sounds off.  Any tips for how to make a melody match a song?  I'm fairly new to making music so I'm not great at melodies or listening to things and figuring out what note it is.  My soundcloud is:

https://soundcloud.com/deblaze_official

I don't know if that will help you to see how far along I am with learning to make music.

I also want people to know that I have tried studying music theory but it has never made much sense or had that much appeal.

Comment: From my experience when I hear my students say something sounds "off" it is due to the fact the the parts that sound "off" are not in the same key.  Obviously I cannot guarantee that is the case here.  Do you know what key that song is in, is your matching part in the same key?

Comment: Have you read the Related posts in the sidebar to the right? Especially the top two. You need to understand the relationship between the existing chord sequences and resolution and the melody you want to use.

Comment: [The song apparently is in C minor](https://www.audiokeychain.com/track/YBx/diplo-revolution-feat-imanos-faustix-kai).  Cminor uses C, D, E♭, F, G, A♭, and B♭. Stick with those, and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

1. Work out the key of the original mix (that the acapella is taken from)
2. *Optional:* Come up with a new chord progression or bassline that stays close to that original key and works well under the acapella. (I say optional because in many cases you may want to re-use the chord progression or bassline of the original)
3. invent some melodic ideas that work with your (possibly new) chord progression or bassline
4. *Optional:* Try to make the new melody relate to the acapella in some way - e.g. you may want to borrow some little bits of the vocal melody to reuse, or work the new melody in and out of the vocal phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to play the acapella notes on a guitar or keyboard. That may help you to visualize the key and hopefully to get the original chord progression (or even better: your own).

It may take you some time to get the melody but, hey: music demands time! Eventually it will become easier to hear the scale, play it and get chords from it.

Hope it helps.